# contenteditable firefox caret with empty paragraphs and placeholder

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have an contenteditable div, and inside an empty paragraph. I've set a placeholder for that paragraph with CSS content property.

```css
div { background-color: #ddd; height: 300px; }
p { background-color: #bbb; height: 16px; }
p:empty:before { content: "Start writing here…" }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

In Chrome, when I put the caret into that paragraph and start writing some text, the text places inside the paragraph. When I press intro it procuces a new paragraph and the new text places inside the new paragraph.

I expect the same behaviour in Firefox, but instead, the text places before the paragraph, and when I press intro to start a new paragraph it introduces a line break instead a new paragraph.

Here is a demo in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpaNqQ

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect each `p` element, you can see that the browser is applying its default margin styling. The extra spacing disappears when you apply `margin: 0` to the `p` elements.

```css
div { background-color: #ddd; height: 300px; }
p { background-color: #bbb; height: 16px; margin: 0; }
p:empty:before { content: "Start writing here…" }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, of course, but that was not what I was asking for. The problem is that in Firefox the caret places before the beginning of the paragraph, so when you start writing the text places before the paragraph, without any `<p>` tag wrapping. The proper behaviour is like it works in browsers with WebKit (chrome or safari) and even in IE. The text you write places inside the paragraph, and when you press intro a new `<p>` tag is created for the new paragraph.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, why do you need the `<p>` elements to begin with? It looks like it works fine in Firefox without them.